# Should I use SSL on SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, ssl

I am trying to setup a web server in Linux (Debian).

I have modified the IP tables to provide access only SSH and HTTP/S.

Also SSH port has been changed to non-standard one.

Apart from these steps, should I be using some sort of SSL while connecting to SSH or SSH is secure by nature?

Comment: Why has this been down-voted?

Answer (score 2):

SSH is secured by default (SSH means Secure SHell), so no steps must be done here. Your setup of SSH on different port is quite useless, it has no advantage in security but it has disadvantage on usability. Don't think that attackers attack ssh server by hand, they have bots which scans all port on target machine and find where ssh is listening.

For better security, you should:

- Setup SSH with key authorization
- Disable authorization by password
- Disable SSH login to root directy
- Use sudo instead of su
- Check your logs at regular basis
- Do regular update
- Think about allowing ssh access only for some IP adresses and/or via VPN

Least, but not last - do regular checks and validation of your setup.

Comment: I can't agree about the inutility of running on a different port.  Although I don't favour it myself, my wife does it on her servers, and it drops her bot counts by a significant amount (about 25% of those on a comparable server with ssh running on port 22, a quick straw poll suggests).  It is true that *some* bots do scan more ports than 22, but by no means do they all.

Answer (score 1):

SSH connections are encrypted by default, so no need for any extra protection!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell